# Model contains null fields when posting back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with my model on a postback. The fields of the model are all null. What am I missing?

Here is my model:

```
public class NewDiscussionModel
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Title")]
        public string Title;

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Message")]
        public string Message;
    }
```

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult NewDiscussion(NewDiscussionModel model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@model Tarantula.Models.NewDiscussionModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/codemiror/lib/codemirror.css".>
<script src="/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="/codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Title);
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message);
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message);
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Mark

Comment: First thing I usually do is put a breakpoint inside the action method and look at the raw request (e.g. `Request.Form`). If there's data there, it's probably a binding issue. If not, then something is probably wrong with the view. If the breakpoint doesn't get hit, there might be a problem with routing, the form action, the HTTP method (GET/POST), etc.

Comment: Shouldn't be closed; problem is quite general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing getters and setters

```
public class NewDiscussionModel
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Title")]
        public string Title {get; set;}

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Message")]
        public string Message{get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm forever forgetting that!

Comment: you're not the only one. i see this problem a lot.