# Form fields are null on POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have simple contact form, this is the (view)model:

```
public class ContactForm
{
    [Required]
    public string Name;
    [Required]
    public string Email;
    [Required]
    public string Subject;
    [Required]
    public string Msg;
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Contact (ContactForm form)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

View:

```
@model myNamespace.ContactForm
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Subject)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Subject)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Msg)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Msg)
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
}
```

Controller's Contact method is called. But param `form` has all fields as null:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Model contains null fields when posting back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600224/model-contains-null-fields-when-posting-back)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need public [**properties**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) with `get` `set` in your Model  not [**fields**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),Currently you have created fields in Model class which will not work for you:

```
public class ContactForm
{
[Required]
public string Name {get;set;}
[Required]
public string Email { get; set;}
[Required]
public string Subject {get;set;}
[Required]
public string Msg{get;set;}
}
```