# View will not pass back data to Controller in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have tried finding my answer for the last 3-4 days.  I have done many searches and got many great answers from people that have already asked basically the same question.  However, none of the fixes are working for me.
This is job related so certain keywords/names have been changed.  I have stepped through the program and the Controller is passing the list data to the View, the View is populating both the Display/Textbox and the hidden fields.  However, the model being returned to the controller has the correct amount of line items, just everything is 0's or null:

MODEL

```
namespace hereismynamespace
{
  public class CommissionCodeModel
  {
    public CommissionCodeModel()
    {
        CommCodes = new List<CommissionListingItem>();
    }

    public List<CommissionListingItem> CommCodes { get; set; }
  }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
namespace hereismynamespace
{
  public class CommissionCodeController : Controller
  {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Manage()
    {
        var model = new CommissionCodeModel();
        var list = CommissionListing.Get(false);
        foreach (CommissionListingItem item in list)
        {
            model.CommCodes.Add(item);
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveData(List<CommissionListingItem> CommCodes)
    {
        //do stuff here

        return View();
    }
  }
}
```

VIEW

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "CommissionCode", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table id="commissionCodesPercentage" class="listing">
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Comm ID</th>
            <th>Comm Code</th>
            <th>Percent</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.CommCodes.Count; i++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.CommCodes[i].CommissionId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.CommCodes[i].CommissionId)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.CommCodes[i].Description)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.CommCodes[i].Description)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CommCodes[i].Rate)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CommCodes[i].Rate)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
    </table>
    <br /><br />   
    <button id="btnCommissionCodesSave" name="submit"type="submit"value="Save">Save</button>
    <button id="btnCommissionCodesCancel">Cancel</button>
```

DEFINITION FOR COMMISSIONLISTINGITEM

```
[Serializable]
public struct CommissionListingItem
{
 private System.Int32 _CommissionId;
 private System.String _Description;
 private System.Double _Rate;
 public System.Int32 CommissionId{get{return _CommissionId;}}
 public System.String Description{get{return _Description;}}
 public System.Double Rate{get{return _Rate;}}
 public CommissionListingItem(
  System.Int32 CommissionId, 
  System.String Description, 
  System.Double Rate) 
 {
  this._CommissionId = CommissionId;
  this._Description = Description;
  this._Rate = Rate;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to investigate the post being sent to your controller and see exactly what is in the data parameter?

Comment: Can you show ``CommissionListingItem`` definition?

Comment: Check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832791/form-fields-are-null-on-post

Comment: It looks like you have fields in class instead of Properties

Comment: I have asked my senior.  We do not have Fiddler on our machines and he has never personally used it.  But when I step through my code and I look at the returned data to the controller, it shows all items on every line is either 0 or null depending on if it is number or text.

Comment: [Serializable]
    public struct CommissionListingItem
    {
private System.Int32 _CommissionId;
private System.String _Description;
private System.Double _Rate;

public System.Int32 CommissionId{get{return _CommissionId;}}
public System.String Description{get{return _Description;}}
public System.Double Rate{get{return _Rate;}}

public CommissionListingItem(
System.Int32 CommissionId, 
System.String Description, 
System.Double Rate) {this._CommissionId = CommissionId;
this._Description = Description;
this._Rate = Rate;
}

Comment: @Terran28 your structure does not have setters only getters add setters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `struct` does not have setters that's the issue because View is unable to set properties hence all are posted with default values:

```
[Serializable] 
public struct CommissionListingItem 
{ 
  private System.Int32 _CommissionId; 
  private System.String _Description; private
  System.Double _Rate; 
  public System.Int32 CommissionId
  {
   get
     {
      return _CommissionId;
     }
   set
     {
       _CommissionId = value;
     }
  } 
 public System.String Description
 {
   get
     {
       return _Description;
     }
   set
     {
       _Description = value;
     }
   } 
  public System.Double Rate
  {
   get{return _Rate;}
   set { _Rate = value;}
  } 
}
```

Comment: This is correct you need to have setters on these properties for the model binder to be able to bind to your model.

Comment: I will try that.  According to the Class it is generated code.  I will adjust to see what happens.  It uses a Stored Procedure to get the info.

Comment: It works!!!!!  My senior is checking to make sure it will not mess with anything else in the system, but the "sets" worked and my model is now returning data to the controller.

Comment: @Terran28 Please mark this as the answer if it's correct, both to award points where they are due and also to help SO.

Answer (score 2):

You model is of type

```
CommissionCodeModel
```

However in your post action you are expecting a model of type

```
List<CommissionListingItem>
```

Therefore the model binder cannot properly bind to your controller model.

Comment: issue is missing setters

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I agree with you that he has no setters on the relevant properties of his CommissionListingItem struct. However even if that was properly written the model binder would fail. Bottom line he has 2 issues at least...

Comment: I agree but according to OP he is getting items in action but with default values

Comment: Amazingly, all *three* answers here are correct. Not sure if I've seen that before. The OP had three separate issues that all would cause this same problem, so fixing just one wouldn't be enough.

Comment: The model gets and sets the List of CommissionListingItem Class where the Get() Method resides.  So it is getting a list from the model and returning a list to the controller from the view.

Answer (score 1):

The model variable should be lowercase inside your lambdas.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.CommCodes.Count; i++)
{
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CommCodes[i].CommissionId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CommCodes[i].CommissionId)
        </td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CommCodes[i].Description)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CommCodes[i].Description)
        </td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CommCodes[i].Rate)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CommCodes[i].Rate)
        </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Still returns 0's and nulls.

Comment: `Model` is a reference to the model being used by the view. In your lambdas, your are declaring a function parameter named `model`. Razor then uses this reference to dynamically discover references to your model. On second thought it shouldn't affect your display, but it would affect you if you tried to use it in a form.